# Chrome console to click

Tags: button, jscript, google-chrome-console

i would like to use the Chrome-console to click on a button.
So far I always used the Id, like:

```
$('[id="vcc-eu5"]').click();
```

or Title

```
$('[title="Delete this view and its saved rules"]').click();
```

of the button, but here, I can not find anything like that.

If I inspect the button I can see this:

```
<a class="wds-button wds-button--primary wds-button--sm apply-btn ">APPLY</a>
```

Is there a way trigger this button somehow? Where can I read about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The currently selected element in the Chrome DevTools is always available as `$0`.

So, you can just select it and the do `$($0).click()`

Or you can use a unique combination of its classes:

```
$('a.wds-button.wds-button--primary.apply-btn').click()
```